# Как переместить существующий контрол в другое окно

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Задача - показать контрол в полноэкранном режиме. Решил создавать полноэкранное окно перемещать туда контрол, а при закрытии этого окна возвращать контрол на место. Создается окно вот так:

```
 function toogleFullScreen() {
    var screenComponent = Qt.createComponent("FullScreenWindow.qml");
    var screen = screenComponent.createObject(root);
    view.parent = screen;  // ошибка Cannot assign QObject* to QQuickItem*
    screen.show();
}
```

Новый родитель не устанавливается, пишет ошибку:

> Cannot assign QObject* to QQuickItem*

Подскажите как делать правильно.

Comment: ответы из подобных не смотрели?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462404/error-cannot-assign-qobject-to-qquickitem

Comment: Там какой-то PopupUtils не известный. Знаете что это?

Comment: Дело не в типе объектов, а в самом подходе.
Поиск по диагонали говорит:


Cannot assign a dynamic created QML object as parent.

The dynamically created QML object has no id attribute.

If you try to assign it as parent like:

child.parent = parentqml;

returns:

error: cannot convert 'QQuickItem*' to 'QObject*'

If you use it as:

child.createObject(parentqml);

It works as espected.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно, использовать свойство [contentItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#contentItem-attached-prop)  родителя, вот так:

```
function toogleFullScreen() 
{
   var screenComponent = Qt.createComponent("FullScreenWindow.qml");
   var screen = screenComponent.createObject(root);
   view.parent = screen.contentItem;
   screen.show();
}
```